# Matching bind parameters in a SQL query

Tags: php, sql, regex

I use parameterized queries, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = :p0 AND baz = :p1
```

My parameter names take the form:

```
^:[a-z]\d+$
```

I'm currently extending `PDOStatement` to provide a method for dumping a fully constructed query, because `PDOStatement::queryString` does not have the bind parameter values replaced.

**What is the most accurate method for matching these parameters inside their query with a regular expression?**

A not-so-accurate initial attempt:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = 'bar:a0bar :u2 barbar :w4' AND baz = :q2 AND boz IN (:z6, :yy1, :q, :r22, :b7)";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(:[a-z]\d+)\b/', $sql, $matches);
$params = $matches[1];
```

This fails because parameters within strings are matched, but I'm not sure it's feasible to avoid this.

Bear in mind that I know full well that no method will be 100% accurate, and this is just for dumping constructed queries to a log file to aid in debugging, so *the resulting queries will not be sent to the database for execution.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution I'm already currently using is probably the most practical.  Anything beyond this would seem to add unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

When I use PDO I pass an array of bind parameters, then I can log the SQL statement and the array together.

If you try to substitute the parameters into the SQL statement the result will not take into account any escaping PDO will perform on your parameters.

Comment: -1 because this does not answer my question, and because PDO does not escape bound parameters.  That's the point of using them in the first place: they don't need to be escaped, because the query is prepared server-side before the parameters are sent, eliminating the need to inject values into the SQL itself.

Comment: [PDO will emulate prepared statements/bound parameters for drivers that do not natively support them ...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but that's not applicable to the driver I'm using, or any of the most commonly used drivers, including Oracle, MSSQL, MySQL, and PostgreSQL.  In fact, I'm not really sure what drivers it would be applicable to... maybe SQLite and other not-really-RDBMS drivers, I guess.